# How to create an entirely self-contained chunk using Webpack 3

Tags: webpack

I am introducing a service worker in my project that will be used for push notifications. I would like to share some common code between the service worker and the rest of my website.

Using Webpack 3 to build my project, my initial approach was to create a separate entry for the service worker and put the resulting file at the root of my output without a hash to give it a consistent web address:

```js
entry: {
  'app': './src/main.js',
  'service-worker': './src/service-worker.js'
},
output: {
  path: config.build.assetsRoot,
  filename: chunkData => {
    return chunkData.chunk.name === 'service-worker'
      ? '[name].js'
      : utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
},
```

I also exclude the service worker from being injected into my HTML:

```js
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: 'index.html',
  inject: true,
  excludeChunks: ['service-worker'],
}),
```

There are also several usages of `CommonsChunkPlugin` that the Vue CLI tool automatically setup when I first created the project:

```js
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  minChunks (module) {
    // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
    return (
      module.resource &&
      /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
      module.resource.indexOf(
        path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
      ) === 0
    )
  }
}),

// extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
// prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'manifest',
  minChunks: Infinity
}),

// This instance extracts shared chunks from code splitted chunks and bundles them
// in a separate chunk, similar to the vendor chunk
// see: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#extra-async-commons-chunk
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'app',
  async: 'vendor-async',
  children: true,
  minChunks: 3
}),
```

The problem I am encountering is that the generated `service-worker.js` file begins like this:

```js
webpackJsonp([17],{"2xmR":function(e,n,_){"use strict";
var t,c,r,a,o,i;t="/path/to/src/service-worker.js",...
```

And the `webpackJsonp` function is not available when the browser tries to run the service worker.

What I would like to do is have Webpack 3 generate `service-worker.js` with all of its dependencies (they are few and I am okay with the duplicated code) and without any of the Webpack utilities.

My searches have come up short. It seems like I want to do the opposite of what `CommonsChunkPlugin` is intended for — but I *do* want those common chunks for the website, just not for the service worker.

How can I go about building one of my entry points with all of its dependencies included in the file and no Webpack utilities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon a [comment on a GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2281#issuecomment-380572642) that led me to this solution. Many thanks to Eric Wood ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556280/eric-wood), [GitHub](https://github.com/eric-wood)) for that comment.

What I learned is that `CommonsChunkPlugin` accepts a `chunks` option to limit which chunks are used as the sources for the common chunk. By providing a list of chunks that excludes my `service-worker` chunk, Webpack will not extract code common to `service-worker` and hence will not introduce the `webpackJsonp` code to dynamically load common code.

With everything else the same, here is the new Webpack plugin configuration that solved my problem:

```js
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'vendor',
  chunks: ['app'],
  minChunks (module) {
    // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
    return (
      module.resource &&
      /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
      module.resource.indexOf(
        path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
      ) === 0
    )
  }
}),

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'manifest',
  chunks: ['app'],
  minChunks: Infinity
}),

new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  name: 'app',
  async: 'vendor-async',
  children: true,
  minChunks: 3
}),
```

Notice that I added `chunks` to both the `vendor` and `manifest` common chunks. The last use of `CommonsChunkPlugin` was already using the `children` option, and Webpack was quick to tell me that `chunks` was not needed.

This results in a `service-worker.js` file without `webpackJsonp` and instead begins like this:

```js
!function(e){var t={};function n(r){ ...
```